# How to generate entity classes with MySQL request?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, mybatis, mybatis-generator

here is a MySQL script below. Can MyBatis create classes with Hibernate annotations based on this script? How to launch it during the build of the Java Maven project?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    order_number VARCHAR(128),
    order_data  VARCHAR(4096),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoices (
    invoice_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        order_id INT UNIQUE,
    INDEX ord_id (order_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
        REFERENCES orders(order_id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE,    
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - MyBatis and Hibernate are very different tools. Are you asking if MyBatis Generator can create classes for Hibernate? If so, then the answer is "no". Hibernate has its own set of code generators.

Comment: Can MyBatis create database and classes from MySQL script during the build?

Comment: No - MyBatis generator needs a database to introspect. MyBatis generator does not read SQL scripts. If you can run this script to create the tables before the generator runs, then it should work.